# Degree of a recursive relationship in the E-R diagram

Tags: database, recursive-query, erd

The **degree** of a relationship type is the number of entity types that participate.

A **recursive relationship** is one in which the same entity participates more than once in the relationship.

According the above definitions degree of a recursive relationship shown in the image below should be 1, but a friend of mine dont't agree and says it should be 2, the problem is I have no source to verify.

[Image of the E-R diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/opC39.jpg)

Please help.

Comment: I cannot guarantee for the reliability of this source, but it says that "A unary relationship is when both participants in the relationship are the same entity.", meaning you are right: https://www.dlsweb.rmit.edu.au/toolbox/ecommerce/tbn_respak/tbn_e2/html/tbn_e2_devsol/er_model_relnshps.htm

Comment: Thank you Adam for the link. Yes according to this link I am right.

Answer (score 0):

I searched on "N-ary relationships" and got, among others, a hit on [this webpage](http://www.vertabelo.com/blog/technical-articles/n-ary-relationship-types).  It lists under Unary Relationshps, a relationship between a person and another person, which falls under your definition of a recursive relationship.  I have also seen these called reflexive relationships, but I've also seen that term used for a different concept.

Answer (score 0):

The **degree** of a relationship type is the number of entity types that participate.

A **recursive relationship**(or **UNARY RELATIONSHIP**) is one in which the *same* entity participates more than once in the relationship.

Since the employee is being managed by a manager(who is himself an employee), therefore, the degree of the relationship is 1.